# React Navigation (native): Overflow visible not working on custom header

Tags: react-native

I'm implementing a custom header for @react-navigation/native-stack. Using React Navigation v6.
One of the elements within the custom header has a native shadow on iOS added (via the `style` prop). The shadow is a tad bigger than the header and unfortunately, I can't get it to display beyond the boundaries of the header. Of course, I've tried using `overflow: visible` on basically every component in the tree, but no success. The shadow is clipped off:
[image]

Here's my custom header:

```js
function CustomHeader(props: NativeStackHeaderProps) {
  const { options, route, navigation } = props;

  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
  const headerHeight = Helpers.getHeaderHeight(insets);

  return (
    <View style={{
      height: headerHeight,
      paddingTop: insets.top,
      width: '100%',
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      paddingLeft: 20,
      paddingRight: 20,
      overflow: 'visible',
    }}
    >
      <View style={{
        flex: 1, display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-start',
      }}
      >
        { options.headerLeft ? options.headerLeft({ canGoBack: false }) : (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => route.name === 'Home'
              ? null
              : navigation.reset({ index: 0, routes: [{ name: 'Home' }] })}
          >
            <Image
              style={{ width: Sizing.logo, height: Sizing.logo }}
              source={Logo}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
      <Text style={{
        textAlign: 'center', color: Colors.purple,
      }}
      >
        {(options.title || route.name).toUpperCase()}
      </Text>
      <View style={{
        flex: 1, display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-end', overflow: 'visible',
      }}
      >
        { options.headerRight ? options.headerRight({ canGoBack: false }) : null}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

The button on the right with the shadow is passed in through the `headerRight` option and contains this shadow style:

```
nativeShadow: {
  shadowColor: Colors.gray,
  shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 8 },
  shadowRadius: Colors.shadows.gray.distance,
  shadowOpacity: 0.5,
},
```

Any idea what I could try next? I don't want to increase the headers' height since this would break the layout elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the menu. I think i was taking another way and maybe you should try it.

Be sure that all the parent elements has at least the same height than the navmenu's height.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Image, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  menuParent: {
    marginLeft: 30,
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignItems: "flex-end",
    flex: 1,
    height: 250
  },
  btnContainer: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    elevation: 50,
    zIndex: 50,
    marginTop: 5
  },
  image: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
  },
  menuContainer: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 5,
    left: -5,
    right: -5,
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    elevation: 10,
    zIndex: 10,
    flex: 1,
    height: 230,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  }
});

export default class DefaultHeaderMenu extends Component {
  
  state = {
    menuVisible: false
  };
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={ styles.menuParent }>
        {this.state.menuVisible ? <View style={ styles.menuContainer }></View> : null }
        <TouchableOpacity 
          style={ styles.btnContainer }
          onPress={ () => this.setState({ menuVisible: !this.state.menuVisible }) }  
        >
          <Image 
            source={ require('@/assets/img/menu.png') } 
            style={ styles.image }
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

This is the component i used and the passed it to nav as headerRight element.
In my case, the problem was that height: 250 was missing in menuParent.

I hope it helps you and good luck

Answer (score -1):

I had a problem like this once and fixed it by using 'zIndex'. Try setting it as the* max index in your project. Hope it helps